# What's the closest fully functional programming languages to Python syntax?

Tags: python, syntax, functional-programming

I know Python has functional programming but I am looking for a fully functional programming language that is served only to functional programming. Any one using python syntax or a closer one?

Answer (score 2):

I would like to through [Scala](http://www.scala-lang.org/) into the discussion. Most likely to python, but also objectoriented and the big advantage is, its not interpreted and can be used together with java as you want to.

Answer (score 1):

Look no further: [Python *is* a functional programming language](https://docs.python.org/dev/howto/functional.html) (and an object-oriented language, and an imperative language).